# SQL - several columns to one

Tags: psql, pervasive

Is it possible to do a query in sql, to turn a several amount of columns to only one?

An example, turn the current database structure:

```
**product_ID | month_A | month_B | month_C**
AAAAA      |      15 |      18 |      16
BBBBB      |      20 |      21 |      26
CCCCC      |      40 |      48 |      41
```

That I would like to change, so I can better use pivot tables in Excel:

```
**product_ID | sales_qt| month**
AAAAA      |      15 |     A
AAAAA      |      18 |     B
AAAAA      |      16 |     C
BBBBB      |      20 |     A
BBBBB      |      21 |     B
BBBBB      |      26 |     C
CCCCC      |      40 |     A
CCCCC      |      48 |     B
CCCCC      |      41 |     C
```

Best regards!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not intimately familiar with Pervasive.  But a standard SQL method would be:

```
select product_ID, month_A as sales_qt, 'A' as month
from t
union all
select product_ID, month_B as sales_qt, 'B' as month
from t
union all
select product_ID, month_C as sales_qt, 'C' as month
from t;
```

Comment: First, thank you for the edit made in my post. Second, thank you for the answer.

About the method, since I simplified the database, in case I have another 5 columns, complementing the product_ID, such as:
price, margin, category, comission and notes
It would be much more complicated?

Comment: @deathseeker . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you provide.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with sample data that is more similar to your actual data and desired results.  Comments are not the right place to ask a question.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that